# I have two WPF controls, but only one of them is refreshing when I refresh their data bindings

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `BindableGrid` control I created in WPF, and I instantiated two of them on my page:

```
<Viewbox Name="galaxyViewbox" Width="400" Height="400" DataContext="{x:Static models:Galaxy.Current}">
    <local:BindableGrid x:Name="galaxyMap" ArraySource="{Binding StarSystemArray}" CellSize="16" BackgroundImage="/Images/Starfield.png">
        <local:BindableGrid.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:TileView ImagePaths="{Binding ImagePaths}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </local:BindableGrid.ItemTemplate>
    </local:BindableGrid>
</Viewbox>

<Viewbox Name="starSystemViewbox" Stretch="Uniform" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{x:Static models:StarSystem.Current}">
    <Grid>
        <local:BindableGrid x:Name="starSystemMap" ArraySource="{Binding SpaceObjectArray}" CellSize="64" BackgroundImage="/Images/Starfield.png">
            <local:BindableGrid.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:TileView ImagePaths="{Binding ImagePaths}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:BindableGrid.ItemTemplate>
        </local:BindableGrid>
        ...
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

Both of them are displaying the appropriate images; however when the current star system occupied by the player ship in my game changes, only the starSystemMap control updates; the galaxyMap control doesn't update as well (it's supposed to show a ship icon on the currently occupied system). I don't see what's so different about how these controls are being bound; I'm calling this code every time the player ship moves to force them to refresh:

```
galaxyMap.GetBindingExpression(BindableGrid.ArraySourceProperty).UpdateTarget();
starSystemMap.GetBindingExpression(BindableGrid.ArraySourceProperty).UpdateTarget();
```

I know there's other code interacting with this; let me know if there's anything else you need to see to figure this out! Thanks!

edit: sharing more details, first BindableGrid.ArraySource:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The array to bind to. Should be a 1D or 2D array.
    /// </summary>
    public Array ArraySource
    {
        get { return (Array)GetValue(ArraySourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ArraySourceProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ArraySource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ArraySourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ArraySource), typeof(Array), typeof(BindableGrid), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

and BindableGrid.OnPropertyChanged:

```
protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);

        if (e.Property == ArraySourceProperty || e.Property == ItemTemplateProperty || e.Property == CellSizeProperty || e.Property == BackgroundImageProperty)
        {
            if (ArraySource != null)
            {
                ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
                RowDefinitions.Clear();
                int width = ArraySource.GetLength(0);
                int height = ArraySource.Rank == 1 ? 1 : ArraySource.GetLength(1);
                for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
                    ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(CellSize) });
                for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
                    RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(CellSize) });
                if (ItemTemplate != null)
                {
                    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
                    {
                        for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
                        {
                            var item = ArraySource.Rank == 1 ? ArraySource.GetValue(x) : ArraySource.GetValue(x, y);
                            var box = Children.Cast<UIElement>().Where(b => (int)b.GetValue(RowProperty) == y && (int)b.GetValue(ColumnProperty) == x && (int)b.GetValue(RowSpanProperty) == 1 && (int)b.GetValue(ColumnSpanProperty) == 1).SingleOrDefault();
                            if (box == null)
                            {
                                box = (UIElement)ItemTemplate.LoadContent();
                                box.SetValue(ColumnProperty, x);
                                box.SetValue(RowProperty, y);
                                Children.Add(box);
                            }
                            if (item == Wormholes.Models.StarSystem.Current)
                            {

                            }
                            box.SetValue(DataContextProperty, item);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (bg != null)
                bg.Source = BackgroundImage;
            else
                bg = new Image { Source = BackgroundImage };
            if (ColumnDefinitions.Count > 0 && RowDefinitions.Count > 0)
            {
                bg.SetValue(ColumnSpanProperty, ColumnDefinitions.Count);
                bg.SetValue(RowSpanProperty, RowDefinitions.Count);
                if (!Children.Contains(bg))
                    Children.Add(bg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

edit: and here's my ImagePaths property which is not being rebound to display the latest images for each star system:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> ImagePaths { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

public void RefreshImagePaths()
{
    ImagePaths.Clear();
    ImagePaths.Add("Star");
    if (Current == this)
    {
        foreach (var ip in PlayerShip.Instance.ImagePaths)
            ImagePaths.Add(ip);
    }
}
```

RefreshImagePaths is called on the star system you move out of and the one you move into when you change star systems.

edit: what's really interesting is that I call `box.SetValue(DataContextProperty, item);` when binding the BindableGrid, but the UI isn't updated for the galaxy map...

edit: here is my TileView.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Wormholes.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for TileView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class TileView : UserControl
    {
        public TileView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Paths to images to display, from back to front Z-index.
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<string> ImagePaths
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(ImagePathsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImagePathsProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ImagePaths.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ImagePathsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ImagePaths), typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(TileView), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(e);

            if (e.Property == ImagePathsProperty)
            {
                grid.Children.Clear();
                if (ImagePaths != null)
                {
                    foreach (var ip in ImagePaths)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var img = new Image { Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(System.IO.Path.Combine("Images", ip + ".png")), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)), Width = Width, Height = Height };
                            grid.Children.Add(img);
                        }
                        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
                        {
                            Console.Error.WriteLine($"Could not find image: {ip}");
                        }
                        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
                        {
                            Console.Error.WriteLine($"Could not find image: {ip}");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the relevant parts of your BindableGrid control, especially the ArraySource implementation. Besides that, you shouldn't be using `GetBindingExpression(...).UpdateTarget()`. Instead, use an ObservableCollection as binding source, with an element type the implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: OK, I added the ArraySource implementation, and also BindableGrid.OnPropertyChanged, in case that helps. As for the ObservableCollection, I have a Map<T> class which contains all the coordinates of objects in my game, and that's wrapped by an array property so I can bind to it easier. So I'd need to make my Map an ObservableCollection somehow? I wonder why it's working for one map and not the other?

Comment: If I replace the BindableGrid with a ListBox to display a list of all my star systems, the map still doesn't update. Maybe that's a useful clue?

Comment: Aha! If I replace the TileView with `<TextBlock Text="{Binding ImagePaths.Count}"/>` then it does refresh! Something's wrong with my TileView!

Comment: I think what's happening is that the `OnPropertyChanged` method of TIleView isn't getting called because the data context never actually changes...

Answer (score 0):

The `OnPropertyChanged` method of my `TileView` was never getting called because the `TileView`'s DataContext and `ImagePaths` never actually changed; only the items inside `ImagePaths` changed. Therefore I had to force a refresh in `BindableGrid.OnPropertyChanged`:

```
box.DataContext = null;
box.DataContext = item;
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but for now, it works!